# Is there any difference between socketpair and pair of unnamed pipes?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, pipe

I would like to know not only user-side differences, but differences / common parts in Linux kernel implementation as well.

Answer (score 29):

- pipes are unidirectional, so you need two pipes to have bidirectional communication, whereas a socketpair is bidirectional.
- pipes are always stream-oriented, whereas socketpairs can be datagram-oriented.
- socketpairs are normal `AF_UNIX` sockets, which means that ancillary messages like `SCM_RIGHTS` and `SCM_CREDENTIALS` can be passed over them.

In the kernel, pipes are implemented in the filesystem code and socketpairs in the networking code.

Comment: I think also socketpairs support partial reads and pipes don't.

Comment: _"pipes are always stream-oriented, whereas socketpairs can be datagram-oriented"._ Linux supports `O_DIRECT` pipes which function in packet mode.

Answer (score 16):

The `shutdown()` and `SCM_RIGHTS` capabilities of socketpairs are needed to implement race-proof communication with subprocesses in a multithreaded program.

Pipes can be duplicated by accident in case several threads `pipe()` and `fork()` at the same time; in that case, the write end of the pipe may never get closed and EOF may never occur on the read end, causing deadlock. Even for those programs that use `fork()` for subprocesses only (ie all `fork()`s are promptly followed by `execve()` in the child), pipe capture by a concurrent `fork()` still races with setting the `FD_CLOEXEC` bit, barring use of the non-portable Linux `pipe2()` system call that accepts `O_CLOEXEC`.

Solving this hazard in a portable way, also for programs that `fork()` without then calling `execve()`, involves socketpairs:

- For an outbound channel (ie, writing from the main program to the subprocess): use a socketpair instead of a pipe and call `shutdown()` before `close()` from the parent to cause a race-proof EOF condition, regardless of whether the file descriptor was duplicated.
- For an inbound channel (ie reading from the subprocess), create a pipe in the child (so that the write end is never visible in the parent for accidental duplication) and send only the read end to the parent over a socketpair with an `SCM_RIGHTS` message.